# Android Taking picture crashes on HTC Desire

Tags: android, camera, autofocus

I have done a small camera app with autofocus in Android. On my nexus one everything works fine but on the htc desire it crashes when i call takePicture() from a Camera object. Here is the stacktrace:

```
10-02 11:53:58.476: DEBUG/QualcommCameraHardware(19448): takePicture(479)
10-02 11:53:58.476: DEBUG/QualcommCameraHardware(19448): val_ril_status = 0,val_wimax_status = 0,val_hotspot_status = 0,val_low_temp_limit = 5.000000,val_batt_temp = 34.000000,val_low_temp_limit = 15,val_batt_cap  = 63
10-02 11:53:58.476: DEBUG/QualcommCameraHardware(19448): FLASHLIGHT is ENABLED
10-02 11:53:58.476: ERROR/mm-camera-config-proc(19448): liboemcamera: config_proc_ctrl_command: SEVERE ERROR: attempt to override pending command 13
10-02 11:53:58.586: INFO/DEBUG(19299): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
10-02 11:53:58.586: INFO/DEBUG(19299): Build fingerprint: 'htc_wwe/htc_bravo/bravo/bravo:2.2/FRF91/226611:user/release-keys'
10-02 11:53:58.586: INFO/DEBUG(19299): pid: 19448, tid: 19628 >>> /system/bin/mediaserver <<<
10-02 11:53:58.586: INFO/DEBUG(19299): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr c0debadd
10-02 11:53:58.586: INFO/DEBUG(19299):  r0 c0debadd  r1 deadbeef  r2 17a3a85e  r3 17a3a85e
... and so on, and so on....
```

i have continous autofocus, but i call takePicture() in the callback function of autofocus, so autofocus should be finished when i am calling takePicture()
after this error the following happens:

```
10-02 11:53:58.916: WARN/Camera(19604): Camera server died!
10-02 11:53:58.916: WARN/Camera(19604): ICamera died
10-02 11:53:58.916: WARN/AudioSystem(92): AudioFlinger server died!
10-02 11:53:58.916: WARN/AudioSystem(92): AudioPolicyService server died!
10-02 11:53:58.916: ERROR/Camera(19604): Error 100
```

and then i get really a lot of MPlayer errors.

So i am guessing, that there is some kind of race condition or something. Can someone explain what the **pending command 13** is the error message is talking about?

there is another stackoverflow question about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277149/nexus-1-taking-photo-severe-error-in-config-proc-ctrl-command-liboemcamera but there is no answer over there.

can someone help me?

much obliged,
Anton

Comment: additional information: i have to run this on android 1.6 (client says so)

Comment: Seen this on Nexus One with Android 2.3.3 when using a variant of the Nov'10 Zxing library

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive, but I believe command 13 is take a picture, and 54 is something like "focus".

I was able to solve my problem by calling 
camera.cancelAutoFocus();

immediately before

camera.takePicture();